# Jinga2 template is not inserting values into the HTML table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

[image: HTML Output]
This is my HTML output which is not desired. When I insert the HTML code shown in the above pic back into the table body(below pic) replacing the `{{context}}` it is giving me the proper output of the values inserted into the HTML table.

[image: python code]
This is the HTML code where Jinja2 template is used. What is the problem in my `{{context}}` for displaying raw HTML rather than inserting into the table?

Comment: I'm not seeing your Python code. I think that would help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Just now I solved this alternatively  by using nested for loops in jinja2 template rather than this HTML code..but thank you for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 escapes HTML by default, and since `context` evidently contains HTML, you'll need to tell Jinja2 that it shouldn't escape it.

```
{{ context|safe }}
```

However, since this leaves you vulnerable for HTML injection vulnerabilities, it's better to (as you found out) just do the formatting in Jinja instead:

```
<tbody>
{% for ... in ... %}
<tr>...
```